# How to setup this X server as a service with upstart?

Tags: boot, xorg, 14.04, upstart, xserver

This is the script I have to make my X Server up and running...
The goal is to make it restart in case of a crash...

```
description "X server"

start on runlevel [2534]
stop on runlevel [!2534]

script
    X :0
end script

respawn
```

So, sometimes it works. Sometimes it doesn't work. How can I do it to be a perfect "always alive job"?

Comment: What do you mean by sometimes it works, and sometimes it does not? Do you have a display manager running? If so, you may want to just use the display manager job with the respawn option.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use "exec ..." instead of "script ... end script", so that Upstart knows the process.

Another issue could be that the job is racing with plymouth or a display manager or something. Make sure display managers are disabled, and change the `start on runlevel [2345]` to `start on filesystem and plymouth-ready` so that plymouth does not try to do stuff with your graphics while the x server is running.